# How to add marker and label to Zbar sdk

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am using zbar SDK to scan QR code, can anyone help me figure out how to add a market and a label with the zbar SDK?

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this for my app.

```
ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
reader.cameraOverlayView = [self CommomOverlay];

-(UIView *)CommomOverlay{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];  
    UIImageView *TopBar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,58)];
    [TopBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"topbar.png"]];
    [view addSubview:TopBar];

    UILabel *Toplabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 9, 300, 30)];
    [Toplabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:11]];
    [Toplabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [Toplabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [Toplabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:76/255.0 green:76/255.0 blue:76/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    [Toplabel setNumberOfLines:1];
    [Toplabel setText:@"Place  QR code inside the viewfinder to scan "];
    [TopBar addSubview:Toplabel];

    UIImageView *FrameImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60,150,193,170)];
    [FrameImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"frame.png"]];
    [view addSubview:FrameImg];
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't use zbar for this, you would just use the normal Xcode label. Watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqxmT6XfRas) tutorial, its great and will teach you how to use the label. The version of Xcode they use in the tutorial may be a little old.